# ASP.NET Core publish of wwwroot subfolders starting with '.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have an ASP.NET Core project where `wwwroot` folder subfolders that start with a letter get published fine but ones that start with `.` do not, e.g. `wwwroot/.auth`

Is there a known reason for that to be the case or does one need to do some special case step in csproj [ and dockerfile ] to include those subfolders starting with `.`?

Comment: traditionally, folders that start with a `.` are hidden folders.  why are you trying to publish these kind of folders?

Comment: @Claies, I'm using it for localhost debugging content only, see [web app easyauth middleware options](https://github.com/kirkone/KK.AspNetCore.EasyAuthAuthentication) but was then confused by why this was not showing up in published site output as I included a test.html file in there.  If this is by design that folders starting with `.` are not included in publish site output then that clarifies why this was happening and is in fact a desirable outcome in this case.  So you can answer question with a "by design" response, versus comment, if you want to get flagged as providing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too, I need to publish some static files in `wwwroot/.well-known` folder for LetsEncrypt validation

Just "include" the folder in the project, then press F4 on its files and in the "properties" set "copy to output folder"

Alternatively just copy-paste this into your .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="wwwroot\.well-known\*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Is the <CopyToOutputDirector/> telling it to copy the contents of .\wellknown to .\PreserveNewest in the output folder?  What if you want to retain the \.wellknown folder name in the output folder?

Comment: @myusrn no, `PreserveNewest` just means "copy if newer". The names stay untouched